# Please Help Me About UITouch (SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create A node from the left and right that when i touch them the bird will fly to the left or right .

1. First I created a bird node
2. Then, I created test node

   ```
   var groundleft = SKSpriteNode()
   groundleft.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)
   groundleft.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 100)
   groundleft.color = UIColor(red: 7, green: 5, blue: 7, alpha: 20)


   groundleft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:    CGSizeMake(self.size.width, 100))
   groundleft.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
   groundleft.zPosition = 0.5

   groundleft.name = "toleft"
   ```
3. Then I implemented touchesBegan

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


   let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
   let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
   let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

   if(touchedNode.name == "toleft"){

       bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
       bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-10, 100))

     }
   }
   ```

Why doesn't it work ??

Comment: Have you created physicsWorld property?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having problems is because the dynamic property of the physicsBody is set to false.

You need to set

```
groundleft.physicsBody?.dynamic = true //Or remove this line, as dynamic is true by default
```

You can read more about the `dynamic` property [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic). As seen in the docs:

> The default value is YES. If the value is NO, the physics body ignores
>   all forces and impulses applied to it. This property is ignored on
>   edge-based bodies; they are automatically static.

You might have set `dynamic` as false because the node might be falling down due to the physicsWorld's gravity. To counter that you can either set the physicsBody's `affectedByGravity` property or change the scene's physicsWorld's `gravity` property altogether.